# Whats the difference between creating object[] objects; and List<object> objects?

Tags: java

I want to know whats the difference between creating an `object[] objects` and `List<object> objects`?

For example lets say I have a class for a book and i wanted to create an object array of books what would the best approach be?

Comment: Take a look here - http://java67.blogspot.nl/2012/12/difference-between-array-vs-arraylist-java.html

Comment: Arrays are, generally, fixed in length, List's can be variable. List's also gave some additional functionality, like contains, indexOf

Comment: Try reading the differences between arrays and lists.

Comment: why am i being downvoted?

Comment: These questions are so many. You might read a documentation, specification,  oracle tutorials. @g9787629

Comment: @g9787629 There are so many questions on same topic. Before you post a question, it will prompt you for similar questions. Please check existing ones, before posting a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply they are two differenct structures.

```
Object[] obj = new Object[4];  // Creates an array of 4 Object
List<Object> obj = new ArrayList<Object>(); // Creates a list
                                            // (ArrayList in this case) of Object
```

An array is a structure that can't change its size.

A list can change it.

A list has many different implementations:

- `ArrayList`
- `LinkedList`
- `Vector`
- other implementations also custom implementations

An array is a predefined data structure that can't be changed.

A list has many predefined functions not present in an array.

Comment: So is there no way to add to an array size. And do you have to define new Object[4] or could you just leave it as Object[] and if so does this mean theis array is dynamic

Comment: Is object using as type of generics? what for?

Comment: @g9787629 You can define an array without initializating it as any other variable and leave the initialization when you know the size. But sometimes is not possible to know the size, if this is the situation a List is a better approach.

Comment: we are using object as an example of a class, the object could of been books for example @AndrewTobilko

Comment: ok i think i understand now. So lists are generally meant for unknown sizes and array list is for known sizes @DavideLorenzoMARINO

Comment: You can see arrays as a building block for more complex data structures. Lists are such more complex data structures. For example ArrayList internally uses arrays with a "trick" to permits variable length.

Answer (score 0):

With a list, you do not have to give a specific number of Items, and you can add whenever you want.
If you know **exactly** how many book instances you need, you can go for an array. But I prefer to use Lists, since it's more comfortable (imo)